# How to get the URL webpack dev server is serving from?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

When running webpack dev server locally, a part of the output is:

```
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from https://some-url.com:4322/
```

Is there a way to get this host URL programmatically within my app?

Answer (score 0):

When you serve your app via webpack, you specify the port and host you want to use to serve the app via CLI flags (`webpack serve --mode development --config webpack.dev.js --port 5000 --host localhost`) or the devServer object in your webpack development config file as shown below.

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    port: 8001,
    ...
  },
};
```

Getting the "webpack output is served from http://xyz" line in your output assumes you properly configured the webpack serve command using either of these methods. Since you already know both the host and the post, which you yourself chose, needing to programmatically access them is rather pointless.

If you really must do this within your webapp programmatically for whatever reason, you can simply access the `window.location` DOM attribute in any javascript / typescript script, which will allow you to resolve both the hostname (`window.location.hostname`) and the port (`window.location.port`). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using auto-selected ports. The actual port is chosen at runtime based on availability, but I needed to access that value in a plugin.

The devServer [`onListening`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserveronlistening) method receives an object which includes a *reference* to the current `compiler`. Because it's a reference, we can assign the active port back into `compiler.options`, and then have access to that value later in webpack's compilation lifecycle, including plugins.

```js
export default {
  devServer: {
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    port: "auto",

    onListening: (devServer) => {
      const port = devServer.server.address().port;
      devServer.compiler.options.devServer.port = port;

      console.log("Listening on auto-port:", port);
    },
  },
};
```

The `compiler` argument passed to plugin's `apply` will now contain the auto-selected port.

```js
export class ExamplePortPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.done.tapPromise("show-port", async (stats) => {
      const { host, port } = compiler.options.devServer;

      console.log("The port auto-port is", port);
    });
  }
}
```